# create invoice line from custom module odoo 13

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I have created a custom module and I have created a button to create an invoice the invoice was created successfully, but the problem is that the invoice line ids only create one line and ignore the other. here is my code

```
    def create_invoice(self):
    invoice = self.env['account.move'].create({
        'type': 'out_invoice',
        'state': 'draft',
        'journal_id': 1,
        'partner_id': self.partner_id.id,
        'amount_untaxed': self.package_price,
        'ref': self.name,
        'invoice_origin': self.name,
        'invoice_line_ids': [(0, 0, self._prepare_invoice_line())]
                           
    })

    return invoice
    
    
def _prepare_invoice_line(self):
    for order in self:
        for line in order.additional_services_ids:
            res = {
                'product_id': line.service_id.id,
                'quantity': line.quantity,
                'name': 'pro',
                'discount': 0,
                'price_unit': line.price_unit,
            }

        return res
```

Comment: What does `_prepare_invoice_line` function return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the multiple lines just do the **loop** over your **data** with the `Odoo` **one2many** syntax of creating data.

**Example Code**:

```
def create_invoice(self):
    invoice = self.env['account.move'].create({
        'type': 'out_invoice',
        'state': 'draft',
        'journal_id': 1,
        'partner_id': self.partner_id.id,
        'amount_untaxed': self.package_price,
        'ref': self.name,
        'invoice_origin': self.name,
        'invoice_line_ids': [(0, 0, {
                    'product_id': line.service_id.id,
                    'quantity': line.quantity,
                    'name': 'pro',
                    'discount': 0,
                    'price_unit': line.price_unit
                    }) for line in self.additional_services_ids] # Multiple Invoice Line Create code here
        })
    return invoice
```

> **(0, 0, { values })** link to a new record that needs to be created with the given values dictionary
> **(1, ID, { values })** update the linked record with id = ID (write values on it)
> **(2, ID)** remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as well)
> **(3, ID)** cut the link to the linked record with id = ID (delete the relationship between the two objects but does not delete the target object itself)
> **(4, ID)** link to existing record with id = ID (adds a relationship)
> **(5, 0, 0)** unlink all (like using **(3, ID)** for all linked records)
> **(6, 0, [IDs])** replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5) then (4, ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)

Comment: This is more compact way to do it. But original is more developer friendly since you can extend or overwrite that _prepare_invoice_line() method from another module without touching create_invoice method.

Answer (score 1):

Odoo many2many fields are pain.

You should have this kind of data structure in your invoice_line_ids

```
[
  (0,0,[invoice_line_1]),
  (0,0, [invoice_line_2]),
  ...
]
```

So modifying your code like this could work:

```
    def create_invoice(self):
    invoice = self.env['account.move'].create({
        'type': 'out_invoice',
        'state': 'draft',
        'journal_id': 1,
        'partner_id': self.partner_id.id,
        'amount_untaxed': self.package_price,
        'ref': self.name,
        'invoice_origin': self.name,
        'invoice_line_ids': [(0, 0, line) for line in self._prepare_invoice_line()]
                           
    })

    return invoice
    
    
def _prepare_invoice_line(self):
    res = []
    for order in self:
        for line in order.additional_services_ids:
            res.append({
                'product_id': line.service_id.id,
                'quantity': line.quantity,
                'name': 'pro',
                'discount': 0,
                'price_unit': line.price_unit,
            })
    return res
```

I don't know if this is a bug or by desing, but I've been banging my head to wall so many times with this.

--- EDIT ---
There was a problem with _prepare_invoice_line -method as well. It was returning only one line instead of list of lines.

Comment: they are more than one line and it's not a many2many field it's one2many.

Comment: more than one line to the invoice line ids dynamic

Comment: Yes. But you need list of tuples with three fields. Now you have a list with a tuple and in that tuples last item is again a list. That does not work.  One2many and many2many works the same way in this context.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot write English today :(

Comment: And now I cannot remember from top of my head should the last item in each tuple be a dict or a dict inside of list. But that is easy to try.

Comment: gave this error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'. sorry to bother you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239360/discussion-between-ex4-and-sh-eb).

Comment: @ex4 with your technique you're looping twice the time on the same data used for line creation which down the performance internally.